# Linux VM in VirtualBox on MacOS Catalina extremely slow

Tags: linux, virtualbox, macos

I have a recent MacBook Pro (2018) with 2.6 GH i7 and 16GB RAM, under the latest version of macOS Catalina (10.15.3).

For reasons I don't know, I cannot run VirtualBox without having the VM to be lagging extremely. I have tried Debian (latest, 64 bits) and Kali Linux (same), and I always get the same result : I cannot even move a window in the VM without having it freezing.

I have tried various VM settings, and am currently with 2GB RAM, 16 MB Video Memory. I tried enabling 3D acceleration without success.

Do you have leads why this is so laggy on a recent MacBook, whereas a friend of mine has a 2012 MPB under the same OS version with the same VMs and has no problem?